# javascript setCookie on form submisson

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Live site- http://www.arif-khan.net/project/newpopup/

I successfully add setCookie function on exit button. So, if anyone close popup then cookie will be stored & popup never appears for him.

Code of close button-

```
<a onClick="document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display='none'; setCookie('abc', 'def', 1)" href="#">X</a>
```

But i need to add same thing on form submission. So if anyone submit form then cookie  will be stored & popup never appears for him. How can i do that?

Form Code-

```
<form action='https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm' name=WebToLeads1020154000000095001 method='POST' onSubmit='javascript:document.charset="UTF-8"; return checkMandatery()' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
...
...
...
<input type='submit' value='Submit' /> 
</form>
```

I already try this but doesn't work-

```
<input type='submit' onclick="setCookie('abc', 'def', 1)" value='Submit' />
```

&

```
<form onSubmit='javascript:document.charset="UTF-8"; return checkMandatery(); setCookie('abc', 'def', 1)' action='https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm' name=WebToLeads1020154000000095001 method='POST'  accept-charset='UTF-8'>
```

Comment: BTW, javascript: is never needed outside of an HREF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what on your site, you use quotes incorrect:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" checkmandatery()'="" return="" ;="" javascript:document.charset="UTF-8" 1);="" 'def',="" abc',="" onsubmit="setCookie(" method="POST" name="WebToLeads1020154000000095001" action="https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm">
```

so try this:

```
<form onSubmit="javascript:document.charset='UTF-8'; setCookie('abc', 'def', 1);  return checkMandatery();" action='https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebToLeadForm' name=WebToLeads1020154000000095001 method='POST'  accept-charset='UTF-8'>
```